# Firebase query to perform posts search Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

1. I have `posts(collection) -> userid(document) -> userposts(collection) -> postid(document) -> fields (postname,description)`.
   How can I perform search based on postname? I want to get post from all users.
2. I have following and followers collection
   `following -> userid(document)->userfollowing (collection) -> all the user ids(documents)`.
   `followers -> userid(document)->userfollowers (collection) -> all the user ids(documents)`.

I have a timeline page the current logged in user should be able to see all the post from users to whom he has followed.

I am ready to change the structure if this is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collectionGroup` query with `where()`:

```
final query = Firestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('posts')
        .where('postname', isEqualTo: 'post_name_to_search')
```

This will return document(s) from `posts` sub-collection of all users that matches the provided name.

Comment: can you please check the question again i have edited it

Comment: @PranathNaik I've seen other question you posted which seems similar. I'll get back asap.